# How to mashall a return of an array of structs from C to C#

Tags: c#, struct, marshalling

Please could I ask for help regarding the following?

I have a function in a C dll which returns an array of structs. I can't change the source code. I have, as a test, written my own C dll to return an array of structs to see, as a first test, how to call this from C#.

So, the stucture is really simple:

```
typedef struct
{
    int version;
    char name[1024];
    double top_depth;
    float latitude;
}Info_Test;
```

Here's my C code of the function I wish to call:

```
Info_Test* GetInfoArray_Test()
{
    static Info_Test dit[2];

    dit[0].version = 1;
    sprintf_s(dit[0].name, 6, "%s", "One");
    dit[0].top_depth = 1.1;
    dit[0].latitude = -1.1f;

    dit[1].version = 2;
    sprintf_s(dit[1].name, 6, "%s", "Two");
    dit[1].top_depth = 2,2;
    dit[1].latitude = -2.2f;

    return &(dit[0]);
}
```

I can call this form a C client with no problem as follows:

```
Info_Test* pDIT = _GetInfoArray_Test();
```

Where _GetInfoArray_Test is a function pointer loaded by dynamically linking to the C dll. Works fine, can reference pDIT[0] and pDIT[1] no problem.

Now, how to call this from C#?

I have the following, but it only gives me access to the first of the two elements in the returned array:

```
[DllImport("MyMathDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr GetInfoArray_Test();

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Info_Test
{
    public int version;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 1024)]
    public string name;
    public double top_depth;
    public float latitude;
}

IntPtr ptr3 = GetInfoArray_Test();
Info_Test dit = (Info_Test)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr3,typeof(Info_Test));
```

So. now I have a copy of the first of the two structs but not the second?

How can I correctly call this function so that I get the array of structs (all 2 of them in this case), not just the first one?

Thanks for any help,
Mitch.

Comment: OK, so I have found a way. Is this acceptable?  int u = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Info_Test));
            IntPtr offset =new IntPtr(ptr3.ToInt64() + u);
            dit = (Info_Test)Marshal.PtrToStructure(offset, typeof(Info_Test));  in this way I can get to each element by offsetting.

Comment: Perhaps create a wrapper struct (in C# only) which contains an array of two `Info_Test` structs (using `UnmanagedType.ByValArray`), and use `Marshal.PtrToStruct` with this? That'll give you your array of two elements

Comment: Make sure the c code have the structures sequentially in memory.  An array of pointers in c may not be sequential memory.  In c# you can create two structures.  One containing an array to 2nd structure.so you can reference by an index instead of an offset.